# ''subsubsection''-level headers not numbered by default

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am a new user of latex. The command `\subsection` is working i.e. it shows me that this heading is subheading of previous heading with number like `1.1.`  But `\subsubsection` is not showing any number, I suppose it should show number like 1.1.1 . but it does not show at all any number.

What could be the issue?

Comment: There is actually no issue: it is working how it is supposed to work - that it "print `section` titles with number and `subsection` without. It's the default settings. If you want the subsection to be numbered, tell it to LaTeX with following command: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`

Comment: Please always post code examples. In most classes macros like `\section` and friends are only numbered down to a certain depth. You are not giving us any information about the class you are using (hence the comment at the beginning), you could try to enable it via `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`

Comment: Plus, this is a LaTeX matter, it has nothing to do with `texniccenter`, which is just a tool to make the code that is being processed by LaTeX

Answer (score 20):

I'm guessing that your document class is either `report`, `book`, `scrreprt`, or `scrbook` -- or a document class that's based on one of these four classes. These document classes have the following setting in common:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

It implies that level-0 (`chapter`), level-1 (`section`), and level-2 (`subsection`) headings are numbered by default, whereas level-3 (`subsubsection`) headings and higher-level headings (e.g., `paragraph` and `subparagraph`) are not numbered.

If you want level-3 headings to be numbered as well, you need to issue the following instruction in the preamble:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

---

Aside: the `article` and `scrartcl` document classes, which do *not* feature level-0 (`chapter`) headers, have the following setting in common: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. For the `memoir` document class, which provides level(-2) [!] headers, the default setting is `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you set:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

any occurrence of `\paragraph` will also be numbered. If you also want to appear these numbered sections in your table of contents, do:

```tex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```