# Missing numbered subsection

Tags: sectioning, lists, sections-paragraphs

I use `\subsection{example}` and on the toc shows `1.4.1 Example`. But on the text only shows `1.4 Example`. The numbered after chapter number `1` and section number `4` is missing. How to add the number for subsection?

Btw i have tried to see some duplicates. Tried their codes but didn't work.

My duplicate: [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338150)

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} %I TRIED THIS BUT DID'NT WORK


\begin{document}


\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{spacing}{0.1}
    \tableofcontents
%   \listoffigures
%   \listoftables
\end{spacing}


\mainmatter 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\chapter*{\textbf{BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{20pt}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN}}  
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace{15pt}
\section{\textbf{Batasan Masalah}}  
\blindtext

\vspace{15pt}
\section{\textbf{Tujuan Penelitian}}  
\blindtext  

\vspace{15pt}
\section{\textbf{Manfaat Penelitian}}  
\blindtext 

\vspace{15pt}
\section{\textbf{Kebaruan Penelitian}}  
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: please upload you entire working code as a MWE

Comment: @jsbibra please see my update

Comment: Please make sure your example actually compiles. Never just ignore compilation errors, After adding two missing `}` and a `d` in `\blintext`, a ``\`` before `setcounter`, removing the blank lines in the `titleformat` setup. The example compiles just fine and the subsection is numbered in TOC and doc.

Comment: @daleif if there's a typo it's my fault. But there's no typo on my main doc. And it still missing. The number behind subsection i mean

Comment: Please copy and paste from your main document so that there's no typo.  And please trim the main document down to the minimal necessary, probably by copying everything to a new file.

Comment: As already mentioned the example you provide here does not compile. The blank lines between the arguments to `\titleformat` gives an error. Remove those 4 blank lines and remember the typo on `setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} %MY ATTEMPT` (its missing ``\`` and it will compile just fine)

Comment: Why are there all those blank lines in the preamble in the first place? It seems like you have copied from an email or something. One cannot have blank lines between options for a macro

Comment: May I ask which editor you are using since you apparently haven't noticed that your document does not compile? Most editors are set up to run in a mode that always produces a PDF file even if there are errors. But, when there are compilation errors LaTeX can only recover and produce a PDF by making guesses and these are often incorrect.

Comment: Hi, guys. i'm really sorry. i've edited my question. Please check the update. Hope you are not tired to help me. Thanks

Comment: @daleif Hi daleif. I'm using TeXstudio. You can compile the current code now.

Comment: Please update your question such that it actually matches your example. There are no chapters numbered with `2` in your example, so it is a bit hard to figure out what you are actually asking here?

Comment: Have a look again at your `\titleformat` for `\subsection` compare with the similar setting for `\section` see if you can spot the problem: hint where is something that are in both that are not suppose to be in both.

Comment: @daleif i mean like this. I want the subsection has the number `1.1.1` but it only shows `1.1` instead

Comment: Additional information. So, I tried to use `\subsubsection` and the output (from my current code in the question) is `1.4.0.1` isn't it weird? I mean it should be `1.4.1.1`

Comment: Of course not, subsubsecttion is the level below subsection. Again look at the `\titleformat` for `\subsetion`, one of the options lists `\thesection`, that needs to be `\thesubsection` (or at least then it works)

Comment: @daleif I feel ashamed for this.  but thanks for the help.

Comment: I was trying to get you to find it yourself as it is a good debugging lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the MWE to actually compile, the problem boils down to this:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
```

which is wrong, note the `\thesection`, it should be

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

to match the fact that it is for `\subsection`