# Why are \subsubsection{} and \subsubsubsection{} not working in overleaf?

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to make my table of contents and the 2nd chapter, I would like to add \subsubsection to the \subsection but is not working. I tried \subsubsubsection and still not working. Any Ideas?

I would like to get something like:

2.2.3.1 Polarization

and same for the Bands

2.3.1.1 VHF
2.3.1.2 UHF  ....

[image: chapter 2 Text looks like this]

EDIT:
main.tex code looks like this:
'''

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage,oneside]{report} % the use of twoside?
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
....
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
......
    
     \chapter*{Abstract}
............


\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
....

\tableofcontents


\include{ch1}

\include{ch2}

\include{ch3}

\include{ch4}

\include{Conclusion}

\listoffigures

\appendix
\include{Appendix}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %plain is for the format
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

'''
As you can see I added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` and is not working, because the table of content is still not showing the subsubsections

[image]

Main.tex has \include{ch2} which means it imports ch2.tex from the left panel  called  chapter 2 "Fundamental Concepts in Electromagnetic Communication" :
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} worked
'''

```
\chapter{Fundamental Concepts in Electromagnetic Communication}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{2. Fundamental Concepts in Electromagnetic Communication}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\section{Frequency}



\subsection{Wavelength and its relationship to frequency}
\subsection{Frequency modulation}
\subsection{Frequency as a carrier wave in communication systems}


\section{Electromagnetic Waves}

\subsection{Maxwell's equations}
\subsection{Electromagnetic spectrum}
\subsection{Properties of electromagnetic waves}
\subsubsection{Polarization}

\section{Frequency Bands}
\subsection{Frequency bands for satellite communication}
\subsubsection{VHF Band}
\subsubsection{UHF Band}
\subsubsection{L-Band}
\subsubsection{S-Band}
\subsubsection{C-Band}
\subsubsection{X-Band}
\subsubsection{Ku-Band}
\subsubsection{Ka-Band}
\subsection{Applications and Advantages}
\subsection{Uplink Frequency}
\subsection{Downlink Frequency}

\section{Polarization}
\subsection{Types of polarization}
\subsubsection{Horizontal}
\subsubsection{Vertical}
\subsubsection{Circular}
\subsubsection{Elliptical}
\subsection{Polarization's impact}
\subsection{Techniques for controlling polarization}


\section{Decibel}
\subsection{Introduction to the decibel}
\subsection{Use of dB in expressing antenna gain}
\subsection{dB as a measure of signal power and amplitude}


\section{Radio Wave Propagation}
\subsection{Different modes of radio wave propagation}
\subsection{Factors affecting radio wave propagation}

\section{Transmission Media}
\subsection{Wireless transmission media}
\subsubsection{Satellite Communication}

\section{Standards and Protocols}
\subsection{Protocol layers}
\subsubsection{TCP}
\subsubsection{IP}
```

'''

Comment: Would https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338150/subsubsection-level-headers-not-numbered-by-default solve your problem?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate but in general please don't post code as an image, make a small complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes and No, It worked in the Chapter 2 section, but not in the table of contents. 

in main.txt I added

'

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents


\include{ch1}

\include{ch2}

\include{ch3}

\include{ch4}

\include{Conclusion}

'

and still not working. https://imgur.com/a/ifCt4vN

Comment: Telling us that you used `\include` doesn't tell us anything, because it doesn't tell us what is in the included files.  Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem you're having.  And be much more explicit: "not working" could mean (1) causes an error, (2) doesn't appear in the table of contents, (3) doesn't appear in the navigation on the left, (4) isn't numbered, and probably others.

Comment: @Teepeemm I added more context to my post below "EDIT"

Comment: @ed190: To have things show up in the ToC, you also need `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`. See [Subsubsection not appearing in the Table of Contents (`report` class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604975/5764)

Comment: @Werner This actually solved my problem!! Thank you!